# C++ Techniques For Newbies

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Is there any good list of techniques + descriptions for C++ newbies.
I was thinking of a list describing RAII, RVO, Lvalues...
This would be for newbies that don't currently understand those techniques or come from other languages where those are not applicable.

Something short & sweet would be preferred :-)

Comment: If this will remain open, it should definitely be Community Wiki. Speaking of wikis, there's a More C++ Idioms wikibook here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms Maybe it's not for complete C++ newbies, but explaining RAII before someone knows what memory allocation is makes little sense anyway.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for an [intermediate level book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Maciej Hehl: But I thought in hacker-dom, laziness is a virtue? ;)

Comment: If we put _lvalue_ on the list, let's make sure the list also has _rvalue_, _prvalue_, _glvalue_, and _xvalue_ (thank you, C++0x, for bringing us such wonderful complexity!)

Comment: It'd be awesome to have an updated list with all new C++0x items as well. Something like the wiki book but condensed. Shortcuts or not having a quick-ref for newbies (not always myself) seems quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're in two very great books authored by the same person.

[Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)
[More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X)

Comment: Add `Effective STL` to that list ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ covers pretty much everything.